# MongoDB slow string query in large database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm doing a project where we are going to visualise flights in the US for a month with d3.js.

I'm new to working with large databases in MongoDB and just started looking at indexing my database to improve the queries.

I have a large db (about 655000 rows) containing all the flights in the US from March 2016, in the format:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58b5fdf5fa5bf5750f9a34b4"),
"MONTH" : 3,
"DAY_OF_MONTH" : 1,
"DAY_OF_WEEK" : 2,
"FL_DATE" : "2016-03-01",
"CARRIER" : "AA",
"TAIL_NUM" : "N793AA",
"FL_NUM" : 1,
"ORIGIN" : "JFK",
"DEST" : "LAX",
"CRS_DEP_TIME" : 900,
"DEP_TIME" : 852,
"DEP_DELAY" : -8,
"DEP_DELAY_NEW" : 0,
"CRS_ARR_TIME" : 1234,
"ARR_TIME" : 1214,
"ARR_DELAY" : -20,
"ARR_DELAY_NEW" : 0,
"CANCELLED" : 0,
"CANCELLATION_CODE" : "",
"CRS_ELAPSED_TIME" : 394,
"ACTUAL_ELAPSED_TIME" : 382,
"AIR_TIME" : 355,
"DISTANCE" : 2475,
"CARRIER_DELAY" : "",
"WEATHER_DELAY" : "",
"NAS_DELAY" : "",
"SECURITY_DELAY" : "",
"LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY" : "",
```

I want to query all the flight that depart from LAX by doing this code, but it is very very slow.

```
app.get('/getflights', (req, res) => {
if(err) console.log(err);
console.log("Loading data from flights...");
db.collection('flightdata')
  .find({ORIGIN:/^JFK/})
  .toArray((err, result) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  res.json(result);
});
```

My question is: How do I optimise this query? Been looking a bunch at the MongoDB docs, but can't wrap my head around how I should go about doing this.

**EDIT**
Added limit and skip after comment, and sure it is faster, but it only fetches 1000 rows, and I need all of the data.

```
db.collection('flightdata').find({ORIGIN:"LAX"}).limit(1000).skip(1000).toArray((err, result) => {
      if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Fetch");
        res.json(result);
    });
```

**EDIT**
When running db.flightdata({ORIGIN:"LAX"}).explain() in the terminal I get:

```
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "58b61138d383ad325b7e8892_infovis.flightdata",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "ORIGIN" : {
            "$eq" : "LAX"
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "ORIGIN" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "_origin",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "ORIGIN" : [ ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "ORIGIN" : [
                    "[\"LAX\", \"LAX\"]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "mtm-0-0-shard-00-00-yf1oj.mongodb.net",
    "port" : 27000,
    "version" : "3.4.2",
    "gitVersion" : "3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b"
},
"ok" : 1
```

Comment: Don't try to get all data as once. Get in chunks. like 100s or 1000s by applying `limit` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#limit-the-number-of-documents-to-return Use `skip` to get next chunk. And also use `index` on the field `ORIGIN`, so it will improve the search

Comment: @Daniel Böök - Do you have index on "origin" key attribute for your collection.

Comment: @Clement Amarnath - Yes, have an ascending index.

Comment: try removing `toArray()` and use the `lean()` option to see if the time reduces

Comment: @node_saini - I'm currently not using mongoose, should I try doing that with lean()?

Comment: then where are you doing all these query work? in mongo shell? or some other ORM like mongoose? you can use lean() if you are using mongoose only.

Comment: Given you're already committed to MongoDB, it's probably not helpful to suggest trying a relational database. The next best thing you can do is reorganize your database in advance of queries.

Currently, your query combs the ENTIRE list of documents for just those satisfying certain criteria. However, such behavior may not be desirable if your criteria never changes. Why not create separate tables for each airport as destination or origin (ie: `LAX_ORIGIN`, `LAX_DESTINATION`)? There might be a great amount of duplicate data, but it would seem that speed is of the essence.

Comment: @node_saini I'm doing them in node.js, tried mongoose and used lean, but with little improvement to performance 

Comment: @Ezra Chang That might be something to look into, you mean splitting the database collection into smaller collections?

Comment: @DanielBöök: Yes. It all depends on how you need to look at the data, however. A rough but significant improvement would be to dump every flight into two tables, in this case `ORIGIN_JFK` and `DESTINATION_LAX`, or similar. So, if you need to look up all flights departing JFK, you just grab all the records from `ORIGIN_JFK`, and it will already be a much smaller subset of all your data. If you need to observe trends pertaining to people leaving from Queens (JFK), you can query that same table, and it will be faster than querying all the data.